# How do I clear the "afterimage" of a drawing?

Tags: c#, graphics

I made a custom transparent control with custom `CreateParams` to draw a line between 2 circles,

```
class BackgroundControl : Control
{
    public List<Line> Lines { get; set; }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Lines != null)
        {
            foreach (Line l in Lines)
            {
                if (l.From != null && l.To != null)
                {
                    e.Graphics.DrawLine(new Pen(Brushes.Black, 1.5f), l.From.Center, l.To.Center);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    protected override void OnPaintBackground(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        
    }

    protected override CreateParams CreateParams
    {
        get
        {
            CreateParams cp = base.CreateParams;
            cp.ExStyle |= 0x00000020; //WS_EX_TRANSPARENT

            return cp;
        }
    }
}
```

But when I dragged the circle around, it creates "afterimages" of the previous draw,

[image]

Which supposed to be like this,

[image]

I tried `e.Graphics.Clear(Color.Transparent);` and `e.Graphics.Clear(Color.Empty);`, but it all turns the whole canvas black.

I also tried to call `Refresh()` and `Invalidate()`, but it "cleared everything"! Including the circles.

I even tried to draw it on an empty `Bitmap` first and then call `DrawImage`, but it still create afterimages.

I'm really out of tricks! Could somebody please be so kind and teach me how to do it?

Much appreciated!

PS. Here is the code to move the circles around.

```
class TransparentPanel:Panel
{
    public Image Image { get; set; }
    public Info Info { get; set; }

    private Point mousePoint=Point.Empty;

    public TransparentPanel()
    {
        Info = new Info();
        this.MouseDown += TransparentPanel_MouseDown;
        this.MouseMove += TransparentPanel_MouseMove;
        this.MouseUp += TransparentPanel_MouseUp;
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        Info.Location = this.Location;
        Info.Size = this.Size;
        if (Image != null)
        {
            if(Image.Size!=this.Size) Image = (Image)(new Bitmap(Image,this.Size));
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(Image, Point.Empty);
        }
    }

    protected override void OnPaintBackground(PaintEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected override CreateParams CreateParams
    {
        get
        {
            CreateParams cp = base.CreateParams;
            cp.ExStyle |= 0x00000020; //WS_EX_TRANSPARENT

            return cp;
        }
    }

    public void TransparentPanel_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left && this.Enabled)
        {
            mousePoint = e.Location;
        }
    }

    public void TransparentPanel_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (mousePoint != Point.Empty && this.Enabled)
        {
            Left = e.X + Left - mousePoint.X;
            Top = e.Y + Top - mousePoint.Y;
            Info.Location = this.Location;
            foreach (Control c in GlobalVariables.MainForm.Controls.Cast<Control>().OrderBy(x=>x.TabIndex))
            {
                c.Refresh();
            }
        }
    }

    public void TransparentPanel_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach(Control c in GlobalVariables.MainForm.Controls.Cast<Control>().OrderBy(x => x.TabIndex))
        {
            c.Refresh();
        }
        mousePoint = Point.Empty;
    }
}
```

And here is the code of `Info` class

```
class Info
{
    public Point Location;
    public Size Size;

    public Point Center
    {
        get
        {
            return new Point(Location.X + Size.Width / 2, Location.Y + Size.Height / 2);
        }
    }

    public Info()
    {
        Location = Point.Empty;
        Size = Size.Empty;
    }

    public Info(Point l,Size s)
    {
        Location = l;
        Size = s;
    }
}
```

Finally here is the code of `Line` class.

```
class Line
{
    public Info From { get; set; }
    public Info To { get; set; }

    public Line()
    {
        From = null;
        To = null;
    }

    public Line(Info f, Info t)
    {
        From =f;
        To =t;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not `e.Graphics.Clear(theControlYoureDrawingOn.BackColor);`?

Comment: @Llama It also turned everything black. Because it's a transparent control with a custom `CreateParams`, so calling `Clear(CustomControl.BackColor);` is no difference from calling `Clear(CustomControl.Transparent);`. And if I set the BackColor to any other color, it will block everything because it's not transparent.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] then.

Comment: @Llama Updated, please take a look.

Comment: Refresh will help if you use it before any of the other stuff you draw.

Comment: @TaW I tried, it didn't work.

Comment: I've done some similar in the past and I redraw the previous line with the same color as the background. So you end up 'erasing' the previous line and then draw the next line with a black color. So just store the previous line you drew, when the next event fires, take the previous line, redraw it with the background color, draw the new line and store that as your 'previous' line.

Comment: @mnemonic OK, thanks! I'll try it out tomorrow!

Comment: @mnemonic I tried it just now, it did not work! I don't really know what else to do!

Comment: @mnemonic I guess my problem is that I'm trying to draw a transparent line! If I draw a "transparent" line, I might as well "not drawing anything"!